# How to handle inheritance?

Tags: java, json, jackson, couchdb, ektorp

I'm using the Ektorp framework as Java "ORM" for CouchDB. It's using Jackson for (de)serialization of the JSON documents.

I have the following hierarchy:

```
public class Animal extends CouchDbDocument {
    private int numberOfLegs;
    // Getters and setters ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String name;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

I have saved 3 `Animal`s and 1 `Dog` to my CouchDB.

When executing `List<Dog> dogs = dogRepository.getAll()`, I get a collection with 4 objects (at 3 of them `name` is `NULL`). This is because Jackson/Ektorp seems to not handle inheritance by default.

So how can I handle inheritance? I would expect not getting 4 objects but only the 1 (`Dog`).

**Update**
I just tried to remove the inheritance. The problem persists. So it seems Ektorp/Jackson aren't able to detect the class type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting the value returned by getAll()?

```
List<Dog> dogs = (List<Dog>)dogRepository.getAll();
```

Comment: No need to cast. All objects are Dogs (also the animal objects- their name is NULL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct jackson how to handle the polymorphic type. Have a look at the jackson annotation @JsonTypeInfo